# CDI Event Injection in Entity is null , why?

Tags: events, dependency-injection, jboss7.x, cdi, seam3

I have an entity:-

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Application{

@Inject
@QualifierName
private Event<Application> applicationXXX;

public void someMethod(){
 applicationXXX.fire(someObject);
}
//BODY
}
```

In MyEventhandler Class , I'm using :

```
public void onXXX(@Observes @QualifierName Object someObject){

}
```

the injection in Application class for Event --- applicationXXX is null.

however the same injection if i do in some other class then
it's not null and working.

can any one help me and point out what I'm missing here ???

can't i inject CDI events in Entity ??? or is there any other method ???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA entities are special, because they're already under management from JPA you need to have producer for them, even then I really doubt the injection would still work. I suggest not using CDI concepts within JPA entities.

For this case I'd call some other middle man class to handle the event firing.